# IPrompts choice using array as parameter

Tags: node.js, botframework

I have an array

```
Var choices = [a , b , c, d....];
```

I want to use:

`builder.prompts.choice(session, "Select one: ", choices, builder.ListStyle.list);`

But I am not sure of the correct format to use an array as a parameter. The documentation says

> choices: {string[]} - List of choices as an array of strings.

Can someone give an example of how to correctly code this?

Comment: For more details, check out the article: [Prompt for user input](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/nodejs/bot-builder-nodejs-dialog-prompt)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example:

```
var choices = ["Musician Explorer", "Musician Search"]
builder.Prompts.choice(session, "How would you like to explore the classical music bot?", choices);
```

Comment: This works and displays my choices in a list. How do I answer? Do I have to type the number from the numbered list of options? Do I have to type the full choice?

Comment: @BrennanCasey Both options are supported! You can type the number or enter the text.